# Firebase security rules for sub collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following structure:

```
+ properties: (collection)
    - address
      status
      type
      ownerId
      renterId
    + offers (collection)
        - id
          amount
          date
        - id
          amount
          date
    + features (collection)
        - id
          name
        - id
          name
```

I would like to allow read access to the `properties` for owner (using `ownerId`), renter (using `renterId`) and admin.

Doing this doesn't seem to work:

```
    match /properties/{property} {
    allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/properties/$(property)).data.renter == request.auth.uid
                    || isOwnerSeller(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/properties/$(property))) 
                    || isAAdmin();
}
```

What am I missing?
Can I also target the offer only?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query that doesn't work the way you expect with the rules.  Rules don't have much meaning without associated queries that they either allow or deny.  Also please show the entire set of rules.  What you're showing now doesn't include a couple functions that could be making a difference.  Since we can't see the query and complete rules, it's impossible for us to say whether or not your rules do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
service firebase.storage {
  // Allow the requestor to read or delete any resource on a path under the
  // user directory.
  match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
    allow read, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  }

  // Allow the requestor to create or update their own images.
  // When 'request.method' == 'delete' this rule and the one matching
  // any path under the user directory would both match and the `delete`
  // would be permitted.

  match /users/{userId}/images/{imageId} {
    // Whether to permit the request depends on the logical OR of all
    // matched rules. This means that even if this rule did not explicitly
    // allow the 'delete' the earlier rule would have.
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && imageId.matches('*.png');
  }
}
```

According the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language) you can set rules with also this way. Follow this example and you should be able to apply your desired rules.